# Displaying, downloading, and saving a jpeg image from server to Windows Phone 8 camera roll

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to retrieve an image from a specific URL, display it in my image box, and then finally save it to my camera roll. This is what I have tried but I am getting a target invocation exception. What does that suggest?

```
private void downloadImg()
    {
        String uri = "http://timenewsfeed.files.wordpress.com/2013/12/doge.jpg";
        Uri imgUri = new Uri(uri, UriKind.Absolute);
        ImageSource imgSource = new BitmapImage(imgUri);

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            imageBox.Source = imgSource;
        }
        );
            using (var mediaLibrary = new MediaLibrary())
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("trying to save photo...");
                    var fileName = "HELLOWORLD.jpg";
                    BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage(imgUri);
                    img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
                    img.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
                    {
                        WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)s);
                        bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
                    };
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        var picture = mediaLibrary.SavePicture(fileName, stream);
                    });
                    // or to cameraroll
                    Debug.WriteLine("photo saved");
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: Or if there's an easier way of doing this, please say so. Thanks.

Comment: Where exactly does the exception get thrown?

Answer (score 1):

I see at least one potential issue with your code. The main issue I see is in the order things execute in your method which could cause the stream to be empty when you try to save it. You do a handling for ImageOpened which fills the stream, but that callback is executed asynchronously. In other words, this

```
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
  {
      var picture = mediaLibrary.SavePicture(fileName, stream);
  });
```

may execute before this

```
WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)s);
bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
```

If you moved the logic for saving up to ImageOpened handler, it may fix the issue. So you'd have something like this...

```
img.ImageOpened += (s, e) =>
  {
      WriteableBitmap bmp = new WriteableBitmap((BitmapImage)s);
      bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, bmp.PixelWidth, bmp.PixelHeight, 0, 100);

      stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
      {
          var picture = mediaLibrary.SavePicture(fileName, stream);
      });
  };
```

Comment: Oh right. I overlooked that one. So that's why I'm getting a null stream. After rearranging my code, the exception is thrown now in the SaveJpeg command. It says it is not supported. But I know I have used this one before, but that time, I was saving a photo taken by the device camera.

Comment: I tried to lower the resolution but I still get a NotSupportedException at the SaveJpeg command. What's the problem here? @igrali

+  $exception {System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.Extensions.SaveJpeg(WriteableBitmap bitmap, Stream targetStream, Int32 targetWidth, Int32 targetHeight, Int32 orientation, Int32 quality)

Comment: @JoeBautista Do you have the ID_CAP_MEDIALIB_PHOTO enabled in the manifest?